# IIS logging sc-win32-status 64 for Asp.Net WebAPI service calls when the request is more from the client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have an Asp.Net WebAPI service.  Client (.net MVC application) is calling the service using Jquery Ajax calls.

When the Request to the service are more from the client (Performance Testing), IIS is logging with **sc-win32-status 64** but with 200 as response with time limit 794017, 1811101. Due to this my webapi service is not responding.

Can anyone please let me what can be done?

Comment: Any light on this would be really helpfull.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what is happening, which may be why you did not get any replies. If you are still needing an answer, would you try to add more detail?